# SQL Count grouped rows for Accordion Panel

Tags: sql, pdo, count, group-by

I have a blog table with two rows:
The only columns that matter for this are:

```
if_blog   data_blog    titulo
1         2017/07/07   title 1
2         2017/07/07   title 2
```

I've created a menu thats ordered by date, and when you click on the date, it drops down the related posts.

The problem is that my query only shows 1 title (probably because of the GROUP BY data_blog.

The query I'm using is:

```
$datasb = $db->query("SELECT * FROM blog GROUP BY data_blog");
$datasb->execute();
while($rows_datas = $datasb->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  echo '
       <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#'.$rows_datas['id_blog'].'">'.$rows_datas['data_blog'].'</a>
          </h4>
       </div>
       <div id="'.$rows_datas['id_blog'].'" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">'.$rows_datas['titulo'].'</div>
       </div>
        ';
}
```

This gives me the correct result of a link **2017/0707**, but only one submenu with title1.

How can I get the total rows of the given date?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, but I don't know if this is the best way:

```
$datasb = $db->query("SELECT * FROM blog GROUP BY data_blog");
$datasb->execute();
   while($rows_datas = $datasb->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       echo '
           <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
             <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#'.$rows_datas['id_blog'].'"> '.$rows_datas['data_blog'].'</a>
             </h4>
           </div>
           <div id="'.$rows_datas['id_blog'].'" class="panel-collapse collapse">
       ';
          $posts = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE data_blog = ?");
          $posts->bindValue(1, $rows_datas['data_blog']);
          $posts->execute();
            while($rows_posts = $posts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
              echo '  
                    <div class="panel-body painel">
                       <a href="">'.$rows_posts['titulo'].'</a>
                    </div>
              ';
            }
      echo '</div>';        
      }
```